# Selenium - Cucumber maven parameterization

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, maven-2, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a test framework using Selenium WebDriver, cucumber-jvm, java. I have properties file with BASE_URL and other necessary  so I can set everything properly in my IDE. But what about in command line?

How can I solve the parameterization of maven in case of different environment? I would like to use something like this in order to set the environment and tags in feature files.

mvn clean test -uat -@test

It would be important for me because I need to use teamcity to trigger these tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the (self :))answer, Hope this helps for others.

You can create several profiles in pom.xml, set the id, properties and you can specify anything you want. in this case, base.url is set within the profile.

Add the following to the pom and you can reach this property with System.getproperty() method.

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <systemProperties>
              <base.url>${base.url}</base.url>
          </systemProperties>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass cmd parameters using `-D` switch, for example `mvn clean test -Dsomeproperty=uat` if you have `someproperty` variable in your build process or something like that. It's hard to tell exactly because we can't see your code.
See here for details about [maven command line options](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html).

Comment: So if I am not mistaken, I need to remove my property file and create maven profile instead? Yes, I don't want to copy-paste the code because the framework is pretty big. I use a propertyReader with input stream to get my URL-s for each environment. But I assume, with -D parameters, I cannot reach my properties file.

Comment: Can't tell because I don't know how your property file looks like. How does your framework decide which environment to use, how do you set this parameter?